# Is it possible to disable react-admin persisting the filters in application state?

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to disable filters being persisted in application state whilst keeping the applied filters in the URL

I've tried the `disableSyncWithLocation` prop, but this removes applied filters from the URL which is part of the functionality I want to keep.

I just don't want previously applied filters to be applied from application state when revisiting a resource list.

Answer (score 1):

Upcoming **react-admin v4.12** will include this PR: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/9019 , which will allow to do exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the answer we are looking for. In the list component pass the storeKey={false} like this `<List storeKey={false} />`. Make sure you are using the latest version of react-admin.